# SQL conditional for a CASE update

Tags: php, mysql, sql, case

I am updating a form in php/SQL. The form successfully updates MYSQL, but it deletes any empty fields. I wanted to try a CASE statement that updates based on whether the form has an entry.

```
CASE
WHEN (variable is set/is not null?) UPDATE `sales` SET `company` ='$company'
END CASE
```

I can't find a way to check if a variable is NULL. Is that possible? What is the syntax?

//extra notes that are probably unnecessary
Below is information about what I was doing in php. This isn't relevant to the question per se, but I have seen that people prefer to get more information.  The form submits to a class and constructor.I was looking into dependency injected classes, but that seems like overkill.

```
<?php
echo "<html>
<form method='POST'>        
<fieldset>              
<input id='company' name='company' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='". $company. "'>";
</fieldset>
</form> 
</html>
?>
```

The post:

```
<?php
if(isset ($_POST ["company"] )){
require 'updatereq.php';
//$update is the constructor
$update= new Salesupdateentry (($_POST ["company"]));
//update is just the SQL update in a php function, which works, but deletes blanks    
$update->__update();
?>
```

//please note- I have slimmed down to one variable, but there are actually 7. I was trying to make it more readable, but a simple if (isset($_POST["company"])) won't work, because there are 6 other POSTS- that have a constructor that need to POST. That was why I was wanting to do it in SQL

```
<?php
class Sales 
{
public $company;  
private $db;
public function __construct($company)
{
   $this->company = $company; 
   $this->db =mysqli_connect("localhost", "databasename", "password", "table");
}

public function __save()
{
$this->company=htmlspecialchars($this->company);

$sql = ("INSERT INTO " . "`sales` " . "(`company`)" . " VALUES " . "('{$this->company}') ;");
return mysqli_query($this->db, $sql);
}
}
```

Comment: can you also show the part of `Salesupdateentry` with the insert statement?

Comment: The actual php code for issueing the query is also relevant. Seeing that you interpolate strings in your SQL, it's safe to guess you're using a dated database interface sans prepared statements. In that case a NULL value from PHP will end up as empty string there.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check if a PHP variable is set inside MySQL.

The better and stable way is to check if the variable is null in PHP and execute a corresponding SQL statement.

If your variable is a MySQL variable you can check if it is null like so:

```
CASE WHEN TABLE.FIELD IS NOT NULL...
```

You could also use the [IFNULL()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function for that purpose.

The NULL value cannot be used with conditional operators in MySQL, so you cannot use  `<, > or =`. Instead you have to use `IS NULL` or `NOT NULL`.

Comment: +1 Oh, you are right. I am going to work on it in php. I hadn't considered breaking up the SQL UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code. I didn't check this. But hope this will work

```
CASE
WHEN (variable IS NOT NULL) UPDATE `sales` SET `company` ='$company'
END CASE
```